# Basic and extended wildcard expansion combined

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob

I'm trying to understand how extended wilcards expansion works and I got into the following problem.

In my current directory `~/t`, I have two files called `chair` and `table`. With the Bash shell, command `ls *(a-z)*` lists both of them, but `ls *(a-z)` doesn't. Why? I have enabled extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob`.

I guess `ls *(a-z)` fails to list both file because in this case the `*` would expand to 0+ characters, as in basic wildcards expansion, and then the `(a-z)` wouldn't expand to anything. If `(a-z)` doesn't expand to anything, Bash will try to match it literally. Since I have no file in my current directory that ends in `(a-z)`, command `ls` fails in this case and lists nothing.

However, according to my previous reasoning, the expression `*(a-z)*` should match only a filename starting with any 0+ characters, followed by the literal "(a-z)", followed by 0+ characters. But that seems is not the case, becuase `ls *(a-z)*` does list my files `chair` and `table`.

```bash
~/t$ ls 
chair  table

~/t$ ls *(a-z)*
chair  table

~/t/$ ls *(a-z)
ls: cannot access '*(a-z)': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `extglob` option enabled, which is why neither glob is a syntax error in the first place.

`*(a-z)` matches zero or more occurrences of the literal string `a-z`, not one or more characters in the *range* `a-z`. Since no files match that pattern, the string is passed literally to `ls`, which doesn't find a file by that name.

`*(a-z)*` matches the same substring, followed by an arbitrary set of characters, so essentially behaves like `*` alone. It expands to `chair` and `table`, which are both passed as separate arguments to `ls`.

If you want to match files starting with 0 or more lowercase letters, use `*([a-z])*`. Ordinary globs have no way to repeat a particular set of characters, only arbitrary characters. Extended globs are equivalent in power to regular expressions, with `*([a-z])` equivalent to the regular expression `[a-z]*`.

Of course, `*([a-z])*` doesn't really make sense, because it will match anything by simply matching 0 lowercase characters followed by anything. Something more sensible would be to match files starting with *one* or more lowercase characters, namely `+([a-z])*`.